# error C2473: 'table' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list. - while trying to make property?

Tags: c#, c++, properties, interface

```
class MyClass
{
string _table;
public:
MyClass(void);
virtual ~MyClass(void);
virtual MyClass load();
public:
string table
{
int get() const { return _table; }
void set(string t) { _table= t; }
}
};
```

I am trying to make a class, MyClass, that is something corresponding to an interface in C#. table should correspond to a property. I don't want to use any macroes or stuff like that. I keep getting the error from the title. How to handle this? Is it possible to make something like this or do I need to implement this like:

```
class MyClass
{
    string _table;


public:
    MyClass(void);
    virtual ~MyClass(void);
    virtual MyClass load();
public:

        string getTable() { return _table; }
        void setTable(string t) { _table = t; }
    }
```

I tried to do it according to this article: [here](http://seanmiddleditch.com/why-c-does-not-need-c-like-properties/)
And I need to override getTable and setTable later on.

Comment: That article does not claim it is valid syntax in C++. It's just made-up. Do consider reading the *whole* article, where he explains why C#-style properties are not even necessary in C++. (Also, this is not an "interface". The equivalent of a C# interface in C++ would be an abstract class with one or more abstract virtual functions.)

Comment: @CodyGray could you please rewrite my code as an example of abstract virtual functions? I'm having trouble getting it.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes Again, this has nothing to do with properties (which is what that article is talking about). An interface is a class that cannot be instantiated, only inherited from.

Answer (score -1):

The error message is correct. Go with your second implementation.